# how to make my raspberry pi act as gateway for eth0 subnet using eth1 internet connection?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, bridge

I have set my **lapton** and **ethernet+wifi router** to an `192.168.10.x` subnet with fixed IP setting.

I have another subnet on `192.168.9.x` range managed by DHCP by a **4G wifi router**.

I have a **raspberry pi** that has an address both to the `10` network (via ethernet) and on the `9` network via usb (seen as eth1 IPv6). How should I configure this raspberry pi to act as gateway and sharethe internet connection available on its eth1 interface to the laptop that is on the `10` network?

Please note I can ping the raspberry pi `10` address from the laptop, so I think I am only missing instructions for the Pi to route things properly and maybe a suitable gateway setting on the laptop.

Here my `ifconfig` on the various devices

*** laptop ***

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether dc:a9:04:6f:28:13
        inet6 fe80::1025:32eb:e83:39d2%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xc
        inet 192.168.10.123 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.10.255
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active
```

*** Router ***

```
MAC Address 
00-11-95-2c-f9-e8
IP Address 
192.168.10.109
Subnet Mask 
255.255.255.0
DHCP Server 
Disabled
```

and the *** raspberry ***

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:09:0a:f5  
          inet addr:192.168.10.110  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1842 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:451 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:482427 (471.1 KiB)  TX bytes:89151 (87.0 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:10:1f:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.9.100  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b0b4:a7ba:fee8:b03/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:28446 (27.7 KiB)  TX bytes:30440 (29.7 KiB)
```

Comment: Have you tried the "Turn a raspberry into a router" instructions already found elsewhere on the web?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. Yes, I read the manual(s). Forgot to mention that most tutorials use DHCP, and I am not. Besides there is a transition in networking from Jessie to Strech that makes more challenging to follow tutorials.

Comment: I have made some progress with iptables (still available in Jessie) `sudo iptables -F;
sudo iptables -t nat -F;
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $wlan -j MASQUERADE;
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $wlan -o $eth -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT;
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $eth -o $wlan -j ACCEPT` as here https://github.com/arpitjindal97/raspbian-recipes/blob/master/wifi-to-eth-route.sh

Comment: FYI https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48307/sharing-the-pis-wifi-connection-through-the-ethernet-port is the cleanest Jessie/Strech-aware tutorial I found.